# Data needed for Google maps API

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3

When using Google API what will be the data that is needed for an application that shows locations of different places,is latitude and longitude will be necessary, the locations that needed to shown is already in Google maps. Or just the address or the name of the place will be enough.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2):

When placing markers on a map at a minimum you need the lat and long vertices.

You can use a various Google APIS for getting data like a Google Places library to search by a place name or address: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

You can also use a reverse geocode service to search by a lat long: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Or if you have your own data you can create the markers like shown in this example:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.166461, -86.771289);

           app.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: (myLatlng),
             data:this,
            map: app.map,
            title: 'Hello marker!!'
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/48asvsed/

Comment: If we have only location of a place, Can we make use of a google API to convert location or name of place to geocode and use it find the location , Is that possible.

Comment: By location do you mean the lat and long values? or the place name?  either way it is possible.  If you have the lat and long you can do a reverse geocode. look at this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Comment: by location I meant the place name , is it possible for google api when uses with an ios app to find the place,, suppose to get directions to that place from your current location we have only place name, no latitude and longitude, is this possible to implement ???